# insert a row into table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a row at first
[image] 
and users can input some info in this row and after click the add button, the row has the info will be store as a new row and show in the table
like:
[image]
here is the code I write:

```
 var insert_html='<tr><td>'+attr.title + '</td><td>' + attr.attribute + '</td><td>' + attr.value + '</td> <td>literal_eval</td> <td class="delete_button">  <button class="delete_attr">delete</button> </td></tr>';
    $(insert_html).insertBefore($(this).closest('tr'));
```

but if I want to add another row continually, it will fail
here is the detail:

https://jsfiddle.net/m8a0v9y8/

It is works at jsfiddle, but when I use it on my big project, everytime I click add, the page is refresh automatically.

so I go through step by step in chrome developer tools, after first everything shows normal as same as in jsfiddle, can add a new row insert before the input row
[image]
[image]
[image]
then page refresh automatically

Comment: looks like you included the wrong fiddle

Comment: @Brino emm, I copy the link but do not know why when you open it, it is empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your insert_html variable is missing opening table row tag. It should be:

```
var insert_html='<tr><td>'+attr.title + '</td><td>' + attr.attribute + '</td><td>' + attr.value + '</td> <td>literal_eval</td> <td class="delete_button">  <button class="delete_attr">delete</button> </td></tr>';
```

Your jsfiddle link is not correct.

Comment: it works, thanks for the help, I though it is some jquery event handle problem